# Why is my base class variable undefined at runtime? I'm initializing it from child classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a parent class that has a variable that I populate from child classes. But at runtime, the expression seems to never be populated. It isn't even null. It's just some random thing that the IDE just says "Expression cannot be evaluated." I've stepped through the initialization code, and it always seems to initialize correctly. But when I call that variable later at runtime, it just throws up it's hands in the air and says it has no idea what this is.

The base class:

```
namespace Events
{
  class MessageReceiver;

  class MessageJoint
  {
  public:
    MessageJoint( Ogre::String id, MessageReceiver* receiver ); 

    void FireEvent( MessageReceiver* from );

    void SetData( boost::any d ){ data = d; }
    void SetIdentifier( Ogre::String id ){ identifier = id; }
    virtual void HandleEvent( boost::any ) = 0;

    void TuneIn( MessageReceiver* r )
    {
      listeners.push_back( r );
    }

    Ogre::String GetIdentifier(){ return identifier; }

    MessageReceiver*                  owner;
    std::vector< MessageReceiver* >   listeners;
    boost::any                        data;

  private:
    Ogre::String                      identifier;
  };
}
```

A child class that consumes the base class:

```
  class JointCloseMenu : public Events::MessageJoint
  {
  public:
    static const Ogre::String cJointCloseMenuId;
    JointCloseMenu( Events::MessageReceiver* receiver ) : Events::MessageJoint( cJointCloseMenuId, receiver ){}
    void HandleEvent( boost::any );
#define JOINTCLOSEMENUNAME Ogre::String("JointCloseMenu")
  };
```

Here's how I'm initializing it. You can see that I'm setting the value of identifier twice!

```
Events::MessageJoint::MessageJoint( Ogre::String id, MessageReceiver* receiver )
      : identifier( id ), owner(receiver), data( 0 )
{ SetIdentifier( id ); }
```

And here's the function where it blows up. It goes in to MessageJoint::GetIdentifier, and inside there, it finds that identifier is not a valid memory address. The IDE just says Expression cannot be evaluated:

```
void Events::MessageJoint::FireEvent( MessageReceiver* from )
{
  Ogre::String blah = GetIdentifier(); //<--KABOOM!!!!
  Message m( from->GetMyAddress(), owner->GetMyAddress(), GetIdentifier(), &data ); 
  EventManager::getInstance()->MessageDispatch( m );
  //}
}
```

I forgot to explain how I'm initializing cJointCloseMenuId. In the implementation file for the JointCloseMenu class, I initialize the name of the string like so:

```
const Ogre::String cJointCloseMenuId;
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `cJointCloseMenuId`? Maybe it's a global initialization order problem.

Comment: If you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), you'll probably find the answer yourself before you post it.

Comment: Perhaps you are calling `FireEvent` on a destructed object. It is hard to say from the information provided.

Comment: guessing object slicing

Comment: So you defined your own String class -- Ogre::String? You need to provide more information for us to help you. A compilable example goes a long way

Comment: I think Ogre::String is from the Ogre3d library. If so, chances are its assignment and copy constructor are implemented correctly.

Comment: @celtschk - Ah! Good call! I should have included that. I'll edit the original posting to help clarify that.

Comment: @jxh - That's a good suggestion, and I thought about that too. But the data I'm initializing it with, which I forgot to add to the original posting, is only destructed when I close the app.

Comment: @PaulRenton - Sorry Paul, I only brought a few of the code files with me to work. I had thought this was enough, but I'm clearly screwing this up in multiple ways. When I get home tonight I'll add more to help troubleshoot. But the Ogre::String class is just a typedef of the standard library implementation. Kindread has it right, it's from the Ogre3d library.

Comment: @user2623609: You would know better, since it is your code. There is no way for me to help verify if that is correct since we don't see the context in which `FireEvent()` is called.

Comment: @user2623609 Thanks for clarifying. I was not aware of the Ogre library. I will check back with the question when you post more tonight

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the problem was. The classes were fine. The accessor I was using to reach the container was passing by value, not reference. So, I would add my instances to the container via my accessor, and they would be immediately discarded when the copy of the container went out of scope. When my code finally got around to attempting to use an instance of my class, they had already been destructed. Doh!